# how to use filter function in scala

Tags: scala

```
case class Transaction(
  transactionId: String,
  accountId: String,
  transactionDay: Int,
  category: String,
  transactionAmount: Double)
```

I created a list like this:

```
val transactions: List[Transaction] = transactionslines.map { line =>
  val split = line.split(',')
  Transaction(split(0), split(1), split(2).toInt, split(3), split(4).toDouble)
}.toList
```

Below command gives the maximum transaction amount by considering all the days but I want to use a filter so that it will consider only previous 5 days of the transaction from the current date and display the maximum value. Can anyone help me in implementing the filter function in the below command

```
val a = transactions.groupBy(_.accountId).mapValues(trans => trans.map(amount => amount.transactionAmount).max).foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(A3,928.88)
(A14,990.14)
(A44,990.11)
(A7,924.59)
(A25,979.22)
(A48,797.19)
```

Comment: What is the semantics of `transactionDay` - what is its reference day? Does it increase or decrease from the past towards the present?

Comment: Value ranges from 1 to 29 for transactionDay and I need to do for all the days

Comment: How would you get the `transactionDate` value for today?

Comment: Please clarify the following:
1. Suppose you have a transaction `t`. How would you determine if it satisfies "previous 5 days from the current date" condition?
2. If all transactions for particular `accountId` do not satisfy "5 days" condition, do you want `accountId` discarded completely or ...?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand how your `transactionDay` column of value `1-29` is correlated to the current date.  Assuming that it represents the number of days before the current day, your filter can be something like the following:

```
val a = transactions.
  filter(trans => trans.transactionDay <= 5).
  groupBy(_.accountId).
  mapValues(trans => trans.map(amount => amount.transactionAmount).max)
```

Comment: OP is asking for previous 5 days but your solution is using previous 5 to 9 days. Isn't that so?

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan, I hypothetically interpreted `transactionDay` as something like day of month, which does seem unlikely.  Updated the answer for a more simplistic interpretation.